# How to control cloth pressure to inflate complex objects

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to make an object inflate and bounce around my scene, it is a vase with some complexities to it. When I try to inflate the object with the cloth physics and pressure turned up, it deforms in on itself - the handles and top half of the vase always fall into the base of the vase. I want the object to remain mostly in tact to its normal geometry, so you can still visualize that it is a vase. How do I adjust the pressure settings of the model so it will maintain its shape and still inflate? I am a beginner with blender physics so any insight on the different settings would be really helpful! (fluid density, pressure scale, etc.) If there is another way to do the same effect would like suggestions too. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe a Lattice deform or a Mesh Deform would be useful to get the effect you’re after with a simplified mesh (eg, subdivided cube) having the cloth deformation and that affecting your actual mesh - this would likely be much simpler to get the deformation you require without distorting your geometry beyond recognition.

Comment: are you using cloth simulation because you want the wrinkles effect?